# Counting characters between grep searches

Tags: grep, files, bioinformatics

Is there a way I can use the grep command in conjunction with a series of other commands to find a character sequence (ie 'GAATTC' in a fasta file) and count how many characters are between each match?

Comment: Better add input file and expected result

Comment: I'll bet my morning coffee that there is already a well-established bioinformatics tool that can do this for you.  Are you aware of the https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ site?

Comment: Fasta files often have the sequence(s) wrapped onto multiple lines, right? I assume answers must take into account the possibility that the tag sequence and the intermediate sequence may be interspersed by newlines at any point.  I'm also assuming that the tag might not be followed by another tag within the same sequence and that the next match may be in the _next_ sequence (or many sequences down the line)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Input file

```
cat file
GAATTCXXXGAATTC
```

#### With shell (GNU `grep`):

```
grep -oP 'GAATTC\K.*(?=GAATTC)' file | tr -d $'\n' | wc -c
3
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `GAATTC` | 'GAATTC' |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) to see if there is: |
| `GAATTC` | 'GAATTC' |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

#### With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F'GAATTC' '{print length($2)}' file
3
```

#### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -nE 'say length $1 if /GAATTC(.*)GAATTC/' file
3
```

Comment: Note that the user mentions Fasta files.  These often contain DNA sequences like these with a fixed line width.  You may therefore have newlines in the tag sequences or in the intermediate sequence.  You also may have multiple sequences in one file, each with a "header line" that is identified by `>` at the start of a line (these could contain more or less any text, including DNA-like sequences of letters).

Comment: Note that OP didn't added required sample input clearly, so OP knows what is a fasta file and can adapt a bit the solution with `XXX` placeholder I guess.